# Feels like I have no clue what I'm doing in my "project" - "GAME"

Tags: object-oriented, game, vba

Never had any programming course. Am not programmer. Does not plan to be.

If anyone has a lot a time to lose, I feel like I have no clue what I'm doing /  that a lot of my code is very badly organized.

It's meant to be a "game". Actualy the game is me coding that.

I'm just looking for a review. Yes it's a lot. I know these kind of shit aren't the main point of these exchange, but I'd like to have an enlighted  opinion on how shitty is that stuff I managed to create losing hours of work.

### ThisWorkbook - Where controls are :

```
Option Explicit
''START GAME''

Sub initialize()
'UserForm1.Show vbModeless
Call GameEvents.init
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
 Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", "ThisWorkbook.OnLeftArrowKeyPress"
 Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", "ThisWorkbook.OnRightArrowKeyPress"
 Application.OnKey "{UP}", "ThisWorkbook.OnUpArrowKeyPress"
 Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", "ThisWorkbook.OnDownArrowKeyPress"
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
 Application.OnKey "{LEFT}", ""
 Application.OnKey "{RIGHT}", ""
 Application.OnKey "{UP}", ""
 Application.OnKey "{DOWN}", ""
End Sub
'Inputs
Sub OnLeftArrowKeyPress()
Call GameEvents.Move(Hero, 0, -1)
If Hero.Character_IsInside(Maze.BossRoom) = True Then
    MsgBox "You Won"
    Call Maze.Generate
End If
End Sub
Sub OnRightArrowKeyPress()
Call GameEvents.Move(Hero, 0, 1)
If Hero.Character_IsInside(Maze.BossRoom) = True Then
    MsgBox "You Won"
    Call Maze.Generate
End If
End Sub
Sub OnUpArrowKeyPress()
Call GameEvents.Move(Hero, -1, 0)
If Hero.Character_IsInside(Maze.BossRoom) = True Then
    MsgBox "You Won"
    Call Maze.Generate
End If
End Sub
Sub OnDownArrowKeyPress()
Call GameEvents.Move(Hero, 1, 0)
If Hero.Character_IsInside(Maze.BossRoom) = True Then
    MsgBox "You Won"
    Call Maze.Generate
End If
End Sub
```

### Combat interface (Not finished) :

```
Dim Enemy As Character
Dim eIndex As Integer

Public Sub LoadChars(h As Character, e As Character, index As String)

Set Enemy = e
eIndex = index

Me.HeroLabel.Caption = h.TheModel
Me.EnemyLabel.Caption = e.TheModel

Me.ATK1.Caption = h.MyAttack
Me.ATK2.Caption = e.MyAttack

Me.HP1.Caption = h.Myhp
Me.HP2.Caption = e.Myhp
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Hero.Character_Myhp = Hero.MyBaseHp - Enemy.MyAttack - 1
Me.HP1.Caption = Hero.Character_Myhp

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

### GameEvents module - Module that lead the game, where is stored everything.

```
Option Explicit

''ENEMIES''
Private Enemies As New Collection
''DOORS''
Private Doors As New Collection
''LOOPS''
Private lpchar As Character
Private lpdoor As Door

''INITIALIZE GAME''
Public Sub init()
    Call Stuff.limpieza(Enemies)
    Call Stuff.limpieza(Doors)
    Set Maze.BossRoom = Nothing

    Call Maze.Generate
    Call SetChar(Hero, 110, 110, "@")
    Call Move(Hero, 0, 0)
    Call SetChar(Enemies(5), Enemies(5).Character_MyPosX, Enemies(5).Character_MyPosY, "S")
    Call Move(Enemies(5), 0, 0)
    Call SetChar(Enemies(6), Enemies(6).Character_MyPosX, Enemies(6).Character_MyPosY, "G")
    Call Move(Enemies(6), 0, 0)

    Dim testitem As New Items
    Call testitem.rnd
    Dim testitem1 As New Items
    Call testitem1.rnd

    Call Hero.AddItemToInventory(testitem)
    Call Hero.AddItemToInventory(testitem1)
End Sub
Public Sub PopulateRoom(WhichRoom As Room)
    Dim CurrentEnemy As New Enemy
    Call SetChar(CurrentEnemy, WhichRoom.x1 + 2, WhichRoom.y1 + 2, "E")
    Enemies.Add CurrentEnemy
    Call CurrentEnemy.Character_Display
End Sub

Public Sub AddDoorToRoom(WhichRoom As Room)
    Dim CurrentDoor As New Door
    Call SetDoor(CurrentDoor, WhichRoom)
    Doors.Add CurrentDoor
    'Call CurrentDoor.DisplayOpen
    Call CurrentDoor.DisplayClosed
End Sub
Sub Move(Who As Character, X As Integer, Y As Integer)
Dim EnemyIndex As Integer

Call Who.DisplayOff

Select Case Cells(Who.MyPosX + X, Who.MyPosY + Y).Value
    Case "W"
        Cells(Who.MyPosX, Who.MyPosY).Value = Who.TheModel

    Case "E", "S", "G"
        EnemyIndex = FindEnemyIndex(Who.MyPosX + X, Who.MyPosY + Y)
        Call OpenFightMenu(Who, Enemies(EnemyIndex), EnemyIndex)

    Case Else
        Who.MyPosX = Who.MyPosX + X
        Who.MyPosY = Who.MyPosY + Y
        Call Who.Display

        If Who.MyPosX > 50 Or Who.MyPosY > 50 Then
            ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Who.MyPosX - 60
            ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = Who.MyPosY - 60
        End If
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub SetChar(char As Character, Optional X As Integer, Optional Y As Integer, Optional Model As String)
    char.MyPosX = X
    char.MyPosY = Y
    char.TheModel = Model
End Sub

Private Sub SetDoor(TheDoor As Door, TheRoom As Room) ''NEED IMPROVEMENT''
Dim longeur As Integer, largeur As Integer 'longeur = x largeur = y
longeur = TheRoom.y2 - TheRoom.y1: largeur = TheRoom.x3 - TheRoom.x1

Select Case TheRoom.MyDirection
    Case 0 'UP
        TheDoor.x1 = TheRoom.x3
        TheDoor.y1 = TheRoom.y1 + Int(longeur / 2)
        TheDoor.x2 = TheRoom.x3 + 1
        TheDoor.y2 = TheRoom.y1 + Int(longeur / 2)

    Case 1 'RIGHT
        TheDoor.x1 = TheRoom.x1 + Int(largeur / 2)
        TheDoor.y1 = TheRoom.y3
        TheDoor.x2 = TheRoom.x1 + Int(largeur / 2)
        TheDoor.y2 = TheRoom.y3 - 1

    Case 2 'BOTTOM
        TheDoor.x1 = TheRoom.x1
        TheDoor.y1 = TheRoom.y1 + Int(longeur / 2)
        TheDoor.x2 = TheRoom.x1 - 1
        TheDoor.y2 = TheRoom.y1 + Int(longeur / 2)

    Case 3 'LEFT
        TheDoor.x1 = TheRoom.x1 + Int(largeur / 2)
        TheDoor.y1 = TheRoom.y2
        TheDoor.x2 = TheRoom.x1 + Int(largeur / 2)
        TheDoor.y2 = TheRoom.y2 + 1
End Select
End Sub
''FIND ENEMY INDEX FROM ENEMIES COLLECTION''
Private Function FindEnemyIndex(X As Integer, Y As Integer) As Integer
Dim TheEnemyIndex As Integer
Dim count As Integer
count = 1 ''COLLECTIONS INITIALIZE AT 1''

    For Each lpchar In Enemies
        If lpchar.MyPosX = X And lpchar.MyPosY = Y Then
            TheEnemyIndex = count
            Exit For
        Else
        count = count + 1
        End If
    Next lpchar

FindEnemyIndex = TheEnemyIndex
End Function


Private Sub OpenFightMenu(h As Character, e As Character, index As Integer)
    Call Fight.LoadChars(h, e, index)
    Fight.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

### Maze - Where the "dungeon" is generated

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0
Private Rooms As New Collection
Private TmpRooms(3) As Room

Public BossRoom As Room ''BOSSROOM''

Sub Generate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
randomize
Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents
Sheets(1).UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

''SETUP START ROOM''
Dim i As Integer, counter As Integer: counter = 0 ''counter needs to be relative to maze size to find good lastroom of maze. 1 is nice for 150*150
Dim ValidAttempts() As Room
Dim current As New Room

If BossRoom Is Nothing Then
    Call SetRoom(current)
Else
Set current = BossRoom
End If

Call SetTmpRooms(current)
Rooms.Add current
current.Draw
Call current.colored(4)

Do While Rooms.count > 0
ValidAttempts = GetValidAttempts(current)
    If ValidAttempts(0) Is Nothing And ValidAttempts(1) Is Nothing And ValidAttempts(2) Is Nothing And ValidAttempts(3) Is Nothing Then
        If counter = 1 Then
            'call clearroom
            Call current.colored(3)
            Set BossRoom = current
            'GameEvents.populateBossRoom
        End If
        Set current = Stuff.Pop(Rooms)
        counter = counter + 1
    Else
        Set current = Stuff.GetRnd(ValidAttempts)
        current.Draw
        Call GameEvents.AddDoorToRoom(current)
        Call GameEvents.PopulateRoom(current)
        Rooms.Add current
    End If
Call SetTmpRooms(current)
Loop

Set current = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Private Function GetValidAttempts(CurrentRoom As Room) As Room()
    Dim i As Integer, count As Integer
    Dim ToTry As New Room
    Dim ValidAttempts(3) As Room

count = 0

For i = 0 To 3
    Set ToTry = New Room
    Call AddRooms(ToTry, CurrentRoom)
    Call AddRooms(ToTry, TmpRooms(i))
    'ToTry.AmIValid LabyrinthSize
    Call ToTry.AmIValid
    If ToTry.ValidOrNot = 1 Then
        Set ValidAttempts(count) = New Room
        Call AddRooms(ValidAttempts(count), ToTry) 'ee
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next i

GetValidAttempts = ValidAttempts
End Function
''ROOMS''
Private Function SetRoom(theroomyouwanttosett As Room, Optional x1 As Integer = 100, Optional y1 As Integer = 100, Optional x2 As Integer = 100, _
Optional y2 As Integer = 120, Optional x3 As Integer = 120, Optional y3 As Integer = 100, Optional x4 As Integer = 100, Optional y4 As Integer = 100, Optional Directio As Integer = 0)
theroomyouwanttosett.x1 = x1
theroomyouwanttosett.y1 = y1
theroomyouwanttosett.x2 = x2
theroomyouwanttosett.y2 = y2
theroomyouwanttosett.x3 = x3
theroomyouwanttosett.y3 = y3
theroomyouwanttosett.x4 = x4
theroomyouwanttosett.y4 = y4
theroomyouwanttosett.MyDirection = Directio
End Function
Private Function AddRooms(theroomyouwanttoset As Room, addroom As Room)
theroomyouwanttoset.x1 = theroomyouwanttoset.x1 + addroom.x1
theroomyouwanttoset.y1 = theroomyouwanttoset.y1 + addroom.y1
theroomyouwanttoset.x2 = theroomyouwanttoset.x2 + addroom.x2
theroomyouwanttoset.y2 = theroomyouwanttoset.y2 + addroom.y2
theroomyouwanttoset.x3 = theroomyouwanttoset.x3 + addroom.x3
theroomyouwanttoset.y3 = theroomyouwanttoset.y3 + addroom.y3
theroomyouwanttoset.x4 = theroomyouwanttoset.x4 + addroom.x4
theroomyouwanttoset.y4 = theroomyouwanttoset.y4 + addroom.y4
theroomyouwanttoset.MyDirection = addroom.MyDirection
End Function
''RANDOMIZE ROOMS''
Private Sub SetTmpRooms(CurrentRoom As Room)
Dim longeur As Integer, largeur As Integer

If Not IsEmpty(TmpRooms) Then Erase TmpRooms

longeur = Int(20 * rnd + 7) 'Columns
largeur = Int(20 * rnd + 7)  ' rows
'up
Set TmpRooms(0) = New Room
Call SetRoom(TmpRooms(0), -largeur, 0, -largeur, 0, CurrentRoom.x1 - CurrentRoom.x3 - 1, 0, CurrentRoom.x1 - CurrentRoom.x3 - 1, 0, 0)
'right
Set TmpRooms(1) = New Room
Call SetRoom(TmpRooms(1), 0, CurrentRoom.y2 - CurrentRoom.y1 + 1, 0, longeur, 0, CurrentRoom.y2 - CurrentRoom.y1 + 1, 0, longeur, 1)
'bot
Set TmpRooms(2) = New Room
Call SetRoom(TmpRooms(2), CurrentRoom.x3 - CurrentRoom.x1 + 1, 0, CurrentRoom.x3 - CurrentRoom.x1 + 1, 0, largeur, 0, largeur, 0, 2)
'left
Set TmpRooms(3) = New Room
Call SetRoom(TmpRooms(3), 0, -longeur, 0, CurrentRoom.y1 - CurrentRoom.y2 - 1, 0, -longeur, 0, CurrentRoom.y1 - CurrentRoom.y2 - 1, 3)
End Sub
```

### Stuff module - For stuff

```
        ''Stuff for second axis randomization on maze''
        'If randomnumber > 0.49 Then
        '    Call SetRoom(TmpRooms(i), -largeur, CurrentRoom.y2 - CurrentRoom.y1 + 1, -largeur, longeur, largeur, CurrentRoom.y2 - CurrentRoom.y1 + 1, largeur, longeur)
        'Else
        '    If largeur > CurrentRoom.x3 - CurrentRoom.x1 Then largeur = 1
        '    Call SetRoom(TmpRooms(i), largeur, CurrentRoom.y2 - CurrentRoom.y1 + 1, largeur, longeur, -largeur, CurrentRoom.y2 - CurrentRoom.y1 + 1, -largeur, longeur)
        'End If
        'If randomnumber > 0.49 Then
        '    Call SetRoom(TmpRooms(i), -largeur, -longeur, -largeur, longeur, CurrentRoom.x1 - CurrentRoom.x3 - 1, -longeur, CurrentRoom.x1 - CurrentRoom.x3 - 1, longeur)
        'Else
        '    If longeur > CurrentRoom.y2 - CurrentRoom.y1 Then longeur = 1
        '    Call SetRoom(TmpRooms(i), -largeur, longeur, -largeur, longeur, CurrentRoom.x1 - CurrentRoom.x3 - 1, longeur, CurrentRoom.x1 - CurrentRoom.x3 - 1, -longeur)
        'End If


''EMPTY COLLECTION''
Sub limpieza(ByRef listilla As Collection)
    While listilla.count <> 0
        listilla.Remove (listilla.count)
    Wend
End Sub
''RANDOM FROM ARRAY''
Function GetRnd(arr)
    Dim a
    Set a = Nothing

    While a Is Nothing
        Set a = arr(rnd * UBound(arr))
    Wend

    Set GetRnd = a
End Function
''STACK''
Function Pop(WhichCollection As Collection) As Variant
    With WhichCollection
        If .count > 0 Then
            Set Pop = .item(.count)
            .Remove .count
        End If
    End With
End Function

Function RandomNameGenerator() As String
'PURPOSE: Create a Randomized String of Characters
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim RND1 As Variant
Dim RND2 As Variant

  RND1 = Array("Sword", "Axe", "Spear", "Dildo", "Pickaxe", "Stick", "Mace", "Hammer", "Gun", "Sniper", _
  "Sextoy", "Strap-On", "Trebuchet", "Catapult", "Balista")

  RND2 = Array("Destruction", "Thousand thuth", "Pleasure", "Joy", "Mightiness", "Reckoning", "Fear", "Pain", "Wood", "Iron", _
  "Mining", "Agility", "Precision", "Superiority", "Defeat", "Death")


'Randomly Select Characters One-by-One
randomize
RandomNameGenerator = RND1(Int((UBound(RND1) - LBound(RND1) + 1) * rnd + LBound(RND1))) & " " & "Of" & " " & RND2(Int((UBound(RND2) - LBound(RND2) + 1) * rnd + LBound(RND2)))

End Function
```

### Characted class module - Used as interface for Enemy class & Hero

```
Option Explicit
''POSITIONS''
Public Property Get MyPosX() As Integer
End Property
Public Property Let MyPosX(v As Integer)
End Property
Public Property Get MyPosY() As Integer
End Property
Public Property Let MyPosY(v As Integer)
End Property
''MODEL''
Public Property Get TheModel() As String
End Property
Public Property Let TheModel(v As String)
End Property
''STATS''
Public Property Get MyAttack() As Integer
End Property
Public Property Get Myhp() As Integer
End Property
Public Property Let Myhp(v As Integer)
End Property
 ''MISC''
Public Sub Display()
End Sub
Public Sub DisplayOff()
End Sub
Public Function IsInside(TheRoom As Room) As Boolean
End Function
```

### Door class module - For doors (Not finished at all)

```
Option Explicit

Private cell1X As Integer, cell1Y As Integer, cell2X As Integer, cell2Y As Integer ''POSITIONS''
Private IsOpen As Boolean ''OPEN OR CLOSED''
''POSITIONS''
Public Property Get x1() As Integer
    x1 = cell1X
End Property
Public Property Get y1() As Integer
    y1 = cell1Y
End Property
Public Property Get x2() As Integer
    x2 = cell2X
End Property
Public Property Get y2() As Integer
    y2 = cell2Y
End Property
Public Property Let x1(newx1 As Integer)
   cell1X = newx1
End Property
Public Property Let y1(newy1 As Integer)
    cell1Y = newy1
End Property
Public Property Let x2(newx2 As Integer)
    cell2X = newx2
End Property
Public Property Let y2(newy2 As Integer)
    cell2Y = newy2
End Property

Sub DisplayOpen()
Cells(cell1X, cell1Y).Value = ""
Cells(cell2X, cell2Y).Value = ""
End Sub
Sub DisplayClosed()
Cells(cell1X, cell1Y).Value = "D"
Cells(cell2X, cell2Y).Value = "D"
End Sub
```

### Enemy class (not finished) - for enemies

```
Implements Character
Option Explicit

Private MyCellX As Integer, MyCellY As Integer 'POSTION
Private hatk As Integer, hdef As Integer, Hhp As Integer 'STATS
Private MyModel As String

''''' CHARACTER INTERFACE ''''

''POSITIONS''
Public Property Get Character_MyPosX() As Integer
    Character_MyPosX = MyCellX
End Property
Public Property Let Character_MyPosX(v As Integer)
    MyCellX = v
End Property
Public Property Get Character_MyPosY() As Integer
    Character_MyPosY = MyCellY
End Property
Public Property Let Character_MyPosY(v As Integer)
    MyCellY = v
End Property
''MODEL''
Public Property Get Character_TheModel() As String
    Character_TheModel = MyModel
End Property
Public Property Let Character_TheModel(v As String)
    MyModel = v
End Property
''STATS''
Public Property Get Character_MyAttack() As Integer
    Character_MyAttack = hatk
End Property
Public Property Get Character_Myhp() As Integer
    Character_Myhp = Hhp
End Property
Public Property Let Character_Myhp(v As Integer) 'For dmg
    Hhp = v
End Property

Sub Character_Display()
Cells(MyCellX, MyCellY).Value = Me.Character_TheModel
End Sub

Sub Character_DisplayOff()
Cells(MyCellX, MyCellY).Value = ""
End Sub

Function Character_IsInside(TheRoom As Room) As Boolean

If Me.Character_MyPosY > TheRoom.y1 And Me.Character_MyPosY < TheRoom.y2 And Me.Character_MyPosX > TheRoom.x1 And Me.Character_MyPosX < TheRoom.x3 Then
    Character_IsInside = True
    Else
    Character_IsInside = False
End If

End Function
```

### Hero class - For you, Predeclared ID

```
Implements Character
Option Explicit
Private hItems(0 To 9) As Items ''
Private MyCellX As Integer, MyCellY As Integer 'POSTION
Private hatk As Integer, hdef As Integer, Hhp As Integer 'STATS
Private MyModel As String ' you, :)
''POSITIONS''
Public Property Get Character_MyPosX() As Integer
    Character_MyPosX = MyCellX
End Property
Public Property Let Character_MyPosX(v As Integer)
    MyCellX = v
End Property
Public Property Get Character_MyPosY() As Integer
    Character_MyPosY = MyCellY
End Property
Public Property Let Character_MyPosY(v As Integer)
    MyCellY = v
End Property
''MODEL''
Public Property Get Character_TheModel() As String
    Character_TheModel = MyModel
End Property
Public Property Let Character_TheModel(v As String)
    MyModel = v
End Property
''STATS''
Public Property Get Character_MyAttack() As Integer
    Character_MyAttack = hatk + GetModifier()(0)
End Property
Public Property Get Character_Myhp() As Integer
    Character_Myhp = Hhp + GetModifier()(1)
End Property
Public Property Get MyBaseHp() As Integer
    MyBaseHp = Hhp
End Property
Public Property Let Character_Myhp(v As Integer) 'For dmg
    Hhp = v
End Property

Public Sub Character_Display()
Cells(MyCellX, MyCellY).Value = Me.Character_TheModel
End Sub

Public Sub Character_DisplayOff()
Cells(MyCellX, MyCellY).Value = ""
End Sub

Public Function Character_IsInside(TheRoom As Room) As Boolean

If Me.Character_MyPosY > TheRoom.y1 And Me.Character_MyPosY < TheRoom.y2 And Me.Character_MyPosX > TheRoom.x1 And Me.Character_MyPosX < TheRoom.x3 Then
    Character_IsInside = True
    Else
    Character_IsInside = False
End If

End Function

Public Sub AddItemToInventory(item As Items)
Static ItemCount As Integer

Set hItems(ItemCount) = item
ItemCount = ItemCount + 1

End Sub

Private Function GetModifier() As Integer()
Dim i As Integer: i = 0
Dim tmparr(0 To 1) As Integer
On Error GoTo err

For i = 0 To UBound(hItems)
On Error Resume Next
    tmparr(0) = tmparr(0) + hItems(i).Iatk
    tmparr(1) = tmparr(1) + hItems(i).Ihp
Next i


GetModifier = tmparr
Exit Function

err:
GetModifier = Split("0|0", "|")

End Function
```

Items class - For items (barely started)

```
Option Explicit
Dim atk As Integer, HP As Integer
Dim ID As Integer
Dim Name As String
Public Property Get Iatk()
Iatk = atk
End Property
Public Property Get Ihp()
Ihp = HP
End Property
Public Property Get Iname()
Iname = Name
End Property
Public Property Get Iid()
Iid = ID
End Property

Public Sub rnd()
atk = 5
HP = 5
Name = Stuff.RandomNameGenerator
End Sub
```

### Rooms class - For maze (X and Y axis are inverted)

```
Option Explicit
''store door positions in order to open / close them
Private TLr As Integer, TLc As Integer, TRr As Integer, TRc As Integer, BLr As Integer, BLc As Integer, BRr As Integer, BRc As Integer 'position
Private IsValid As Integer
Private direction As Integer
Private HasBeenRevisited As Boolean
''VALIDITY''
Public Property Get Visited() As Boolean
    Visited = HasBeenRevisited
End Property
Public Property Let Visited(Visited2 As Boolean)
    HasBeenRevisited = Visited2
End Property
''DIRECTION''
Public Property Get MyDirection() As Integer
    MyDirection = direction
End Property
Public Property Let MyDirection(MyDirection2 As Integer)
    direction = MyDirection2
End Property
''VALIDITY''
Public Property Get ValidOrNot() As Integer
    ValidOrNot = IsValid
End Property
''POSITIONS''
Public Property Get x1() As Integer
    x1 = TLr
End Property
Public Property Get y1() As Integer
    y1 = TLc
End Property
Public Property Get x2() As Integer
    x2 = TRr
End Property
Public Property Get y2() As Integer
    y2 = TRc
End Property
Public Property Get x3() As Integer
    x3 = BLr
End Property
Public Property Get y3() As Integer
    y3 = BLc
End Property
Public Property Get x4() As Integer
    x4 = BRr
End Property
Public Property Get y4() As Integer
    y4 = BRc
End Property
Public Property Let x1(newx1 As Integer)
   TLr = newx1
End Property
Public Property Let y1(newy1 As Integer)
    TLc = newy1
End Property
Public Property Let x2(newx2 As Integer)
    TRr = newx2
End Property
Public Property Let y2(newy2 As Integer)
    TRc = newy2
End Property
Public Property Let x3(newx3 As Integer)
    BLr = newx3
End Property
Public Property Let y3(newy3 As Integer)
    BLc = newy3
End Property
Public Property Let x4(newx4 As Integer)
    BRr = newx4
End Property
Public Property Let y4(newy4 As Integer)
    BRc = newy4
End Property
Sub Draw()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, longeur As Integer, largeur As Integer 'longeur = x largeur = y
i = 0: j = 0
longeur = TRc - TLc: largeur = BLr - TLr
    For i = 0 To longeur
        Cells(TLr, TLc + i).Value = "W"
        Cells(BLr, BLc + i).Value = "W"
    Next i

    For j = 1 To largeur - 1
        Cells(TLr + j, TLc).Value = "W"
        Cells(TRr + j, TRc).Value = "W"
    Next j
    'call me.flavor

End Sub
Sub Flavor()

End Sub

Sub colored(color As Integer)
Dim longeur As Integer, largeur As Integer, i As Byte, j As Byte
longeur = TRc - TLc: largeur = BLr - TLr
i = 0: j = 0
        For i = 1 To longeur - 1
            For j = 1 To largeur - 1
                Cells(TLr + j, TLc + i).Interior.ColorIndex = color
            Next j
        Next i
End Sub
Function AmIValid() As Integer 'need add size parameters
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, longeur As Integer, largeur As Integer 'longeur = x largeur = y
i = 0: j = 0
IsValid = 1
longeur = TRc - TLc: largeur = BLr - TLr

If longeur < 3 Or largeur < 3 Then
    IsValid = 2
    Else
        For i = 0 To longeur
            If Cells(TLr, TLc + i).Value = "W" Or Cells(BLr, BLc + i).Value = "W" Or TLr < 100 Or TLc < 100 Or BRr > 150 Or BRc > 150 Then IsValid = 2 'SIZE OF MAZE needs to be passed to inputbox
        Next i
        For j = 1 To largeur - 1
            If Cells(TLr + j, TLc).Value = "W" Or Cells(TRr + j, TRc).Value = "W" Then IsValid = 2
        Next j
    End If
AmIValid = IsValid
End Function
```

Comment: I don't mind spending a lot of time reviewing code - but I'm not going to try to infer the purpose of that code by reading it. Please [edit] 1) your title, so that it summarizes the purpose of the code, and 2) the question body, so that it describes what's what and why it's there.

Comment: "Never had any programming course. Am not programmer. Does not plan to be.". And yet, you are now writing a program - and a game at that! So, despite your plans, you are now a programmer.

Comment: You know, for a non-programmer, I'm thoroughly impressed with the use of classes/objects, the PredeclaredID and `static` locals - these are things many, *many* VBA programmers that have been coding for *years* often don't even bother *trying* to understand or experiment with... thumbs up! I'd recommend further editing this post ([edit]) to add more information/context about what the purpose of everything is - picture yourself presenting your project to someone that's never seen it (which, it kinda is ;-). Side note, I've flagged your post so a moderator can help you get your logins sorted out.

Comment: Can you add a description of what your game is supposed to do? It's hard to see where you went wrong if we have no clue what it's supposed to do.

Comment: specific question time (I know you devs like that)  : How could I improve my Room.AmIValid Method. 
I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306316/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap-each-other
I'm too retarded to manage a sucessfull implementation and i'm stuck with the two loops that check cells value. HELP !

Comment: Another question comes to my mind but you are not going to like it. It's not  specific.
How would I do to add save system ? There must be a smarter way than saving every varaible of the game.